# SWIFT TableView not responding

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, subview

I have a problem, i have a controller, and in viewdidload, i try to load a subview created from a xib file.

My "custom" subview is well added to my first controller but the tableview isn't responding... i mean it doesn't scroll, and when i click it, nothing happens... (i haven't implemented yet the method to trigger an action when a cell is clicked, but the celle isn't highlighted when clicked).

Here the code :

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let v1 = MyViewTest(frame: CGRectZero)

        v1.tableView.dataSource = self
        v1.tableView.delegate = self

        self.view.addSubview(v1)


    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //datasource method returning the what cell contains
        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "MyTestCell")
        //reusing the previous scrolled cells from table view(if any)
        //cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = "test"
        //passing each elements of the array to cell
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //datasource method returning no. of rows
        return 14
    }


}
```

here the code in MyViewTest

```
class MyViewTest: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    var view:UIView!

    let nibName:String = "MyViewTest"

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame:frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        //fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }


    func setup() {
        view = loadViewFromNib()

        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        let sWidth = screenSize.width
        let sHeight = screenSize.height
        let xPos = sWidth/2-(view.bounds.width/2)
        let yPos = sHeight/2-(view.bounds.height/2)

        view.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, view.bounds.width, view.bounds.height)

        addSubview(view)
    }

    func loadViewFromNib () -> UIView {
        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
        let mview = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

        return mview
    }


}
```

in the xib file, i only have a view with a label and my tableview in. The xib file is associated with its class (in identifier).

[image]

If you know why my table view isn't working it would be great thx !

Comment: it looks like v1 may be getting all the touches since it's on top of the tableview. Set the background of v1 to some color(or use the view debugger) and check this.

Comment: I added a print screen of my xib file, i already had a color for v1...

Comment: You seem to set the frame of the MyTestView to CGRectZero. You then add your table as a subview of this view with the frame size set up. As MyTestView has 0 width and height and the default for a view is to not clip subviews I imagine you can see the table but not click it. Try setting the frame of your MyTestView to the screen size?

Comment: Indeed i also posted my issue on apple developer forum and this is exactly the answer i got and you are right. I came here to write the solution but you already gave it. Anyway thank you for answering me because i was quite desperate with this and your answer would have helped me !

Comment: Glad to help. I posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to set the frame of the MyTestView to CGRectZero.

You then add your table as a subview of this view with the frame size set up. As MyTestView has 0 width and height and the default for a view is to not clip subviews I imagine you can see the table but not click it.

Try setting the frame of your MyTestView to the screen size?

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens because I instantiate my MyViewTest with CGRectZero. If i use a CGRectMake for example with actual width and height it works great.

See rory mckinnel post just above for more details :-)